# Wrap comma separated numbers in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to wrap comma separated numbers in an Excel cell through below code.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").WrapText = True
```

Numbers are wrapped but those at the end are broken.

Ex.: `Nos. 12345345,56891235,12458963,12568745`

Are displayed as,

```
12345345,56891235,1245  
8963,12568745
```

I want these displayed as

```
12345345,56891235,  
12458963,12568745
```

Comment: can't you just make the column wider?

Comment: Tried. Making the column wider will not work here as nos. quantity is unpredictable.

Comment: Put a space between the comma and the next number.

Comment: @Scott Thanks. It works.
But, Last number row not getting displayed even if i have used Autofit. We have increase cell height manually.


`code` Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").EntireRow.Autofit`code`

Comment: When you have text wraps enabled, sometimes the AutoFit row height does not deal with it - unless it needs to shrink down. So, you should change the row height to way taller than 2 rows (say 3 times the current), then use AutoFit.